# @electron/remote's getCurrentWindow doesn't return the full window object

Tags: electron, ipc, structured-clone

When using `@electron/remote`, the results of `remote.getCurrentWindow()` lack all the additional properties/methods of the window that are accessible from the `main` process, and used to be accessible when using `remote.getCurrentWindow()` with the built-in `remote`. For example:

**@electron/remote**

```js
  const remote = require('@electron/remote');
  console.log(remote.getCurrentWindow().isFullScreen); // undefined
```

**original remote module**

```js
  const { remote } = require('electron');
  console.log(remote.getCurrentWindow().isFullScreen); // true/false
```

What's the reason for this difference in behavior? It's not documented anywhere that I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Put `nodeIntegration: true` `contextIsolation: false` in `webPreferences` of mainWindow. May be this can be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is poor security practice and won't help here regardless.